# How to set to timestamp when creating a partitioned table in bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

This is what i have tried

```
#standardSQL
 CREATE TABLE dataSet.myTableName (userName string, DateCreated DATE, email string)
 PARTITION BY DateCreated
 OPTIONS(
   description="a table partitioned by DateCreated"
 )
```

but in this case the DateCreated field is of Date type, I wanted to make it TIMESTAMP format, how do i do that? because my data is comes in this format "DateCreated":"1519302159.042" not in DATE type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't be able to load data of that form directly into the BigQuery table. You have a couple of options, though:

- Use a staging table.

  1. Create a separate table where the `DateCreated` column has type `FLOAT64`.
  2. Load your data into this staging table from CSV, JSON, or whatever format it's in.
  3. Run an `INSERT` statement to insert into the partitioned table `dataSet.myTableName`. You can convert `DateCreated` using `DATE(TIMESTAMP_MILLIS(CAST(DateCreated * 1000 AS INT64))) AS DateCreated`; this takes the `FLOAT64` column and converts it to a `DATE`. If desired, you can pass a time zone to the `DATE` function. The default is UTC.
- Use a tool outside of BigQuery to process the data before loading it.

  - [Cloud Dataprep](https://cloud.google.com/dataprep/) is designed for the purpose of processing data.
  - [Cloud Dataflow](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/) lets you run custom code to process data and scale as needed.

My personal opinion: I would use BigQuery for all of your processing needs since you can just run queries.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE
  blockchains.timestamp_based_partitioned_transactions ( 
    status STRING NOT NULL,
    transactionHash STRING NOT NULL,
    blockNumber INT64 NOT NULL,
    sender STRING NOT NULL,
    receiver STRING NOT NULL,
    timestamp TIMESTAMP NOT NULL
    )
PARTITION BY
   DATE(timestamp)
```